# Rails Date Picker Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, rails-i18n

I am using the following gem in my rails app - https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails.

My form looks as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@customer,@job], html: {class:'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_form) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :install, collection: ["Yes", "No"], input_html: {class:'form-control'}, prompt: "Installing?" %>
  <%= f.input :delivery, collection: ["Yes", "No"], input_html: {class:'form-control'}, prompt: "Delivering?" %>
  <%= f.input :job_tag, input_html: {class:'form-control'} %>
  <%= f.input :install_date, :as => :date_picker, input_html: { class: "datepicker"} %>    
  <%= f.input :box_count, input_html: {class:'form-control'} %>
  <%= f.input :cabinet_cost, input_html: {class:'form-control'} %>
  <%= f.input :counter_top_cost, input_html: {class:'form-control'} %>
  <%= f.input :install_cost, input_html: {class:'form-control'} %>
  <br />
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create Job", class: "col-md-3 bump-right" %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form I get the following error:

```
I18n::ArgumentError in Jobs#create 
Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "29/08/2014" given.
```

Does anyone know why this error is thrown and how I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column in your database for `install_date` needs to be a `date` or `datetime` type. It looks like you are storing the date as a string instead.

Comment: thanks - this did the trick - I'm new to this so sometimes the problem is identifying the actual origin of my error.